# macOS Mojave boot option disappeared from rEFInd, grub error at boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac, macosx, grub-efi

I’m seriously panicking right now.
I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS in a second partition on my iMac (macOS Mojave) and after a couple hours of using it, I decided that I didn’t like it anymore.

So I booted back to macOS (from rEFInd boot screen) and tried removing Ubuntu’s partition from Disk Utility.

Disk Utility gave me an error saying that it couldn’t repartition the hard disk, but Ubuntu’s partition disappeared from the settings, without freeing the used space.

So I decided to restart my iMac once again, and macOS disappeared from rEFInd’s boot screen.

Also normal boot gives me a “grub” screen instead of booting into Ubuntu.

I really hope it can be fixed. Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This likely means the ubuntu entry is still in the EFI partition.
You can boot in recovery mode by holding the command + R keys at boot time.

**Make sure to make a backup if you don't have one!**

You can run disk aid first and repair the partitions and see if that helps.
If not, in the top bar choose Terminal and run:

```
diskutil list
```

and find the EFI partion.
The partition name in the example is when it's disk 0, partition 1 (change accordingly).
Mount it with the command:

```
diskutil mount disk0s1
```

Then remove the ubuntu entry:

```
cd /Volumes/EFI/EFI
rm -r ubuntu
cd 
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

There may be other unwanted folders there, the Apple one you want to keep.
If that doesn't work, you can do a reinstall, again by booting to Recovery and selecting that option.
If that doesn't work, there may be issues with the disk.
You can try to boot from an external drive then and see if you an access the data and make a backup if you were enable to before.

Then try a complete reinstall wiping the disk if you get errors with that, the issue may be physical, not software and it's likely time to replace the disk.